# Constructing a query string for JQuery getJSON for a public API GET request

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, http

I am developing a Meteor web app that uses a public API.

I am having trouble constructing a query string that can use the 'LIKE' operator as in SQL or SOQL.

I want to make the call like this:

```
$.getJSON( api_url, function( data ) {
                $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
                    ... do stuff ...
    }
}
```

where api_url is a string that has been concatenated.
This works fine:

```
 https://opendata.miamidade.gov/resource/dj6j-qg5t.json?case_owner=Animal_Services
```

However, suppose instead of Animal_Services I want to search for a pattern on the case_owner field. I want to effectively search for all rows where case_owner begins with "Public_Works"

The pseudocode might be something like this:

```
SELECT * from Table WHERE case_owner LIKE '%Public_Works%'
```

This is mostly a matter of syntax, but I am not sure how to proceed. I have checked the JQuery documentation for the $.getJSON method, and also looked at some SOQL threads on the SalesForce developer forums. However, for the constraints of this project, it must be a string entered with $.getJSON

I am using Meteor, if that matters. If anybody could point me in the right direction, that would be very helpful. I am finding it difficult to search for answers because the concerned operator is 'LIKE' which is not a very powerful search term on Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i actually checked the documentation of opendata.miamidade and you can do a wide variety search with $q

```
var search = 'Public'; //will return everything that have public 
var url = "https://opendata.miamidade.gov/resource/dj6j-qg5t.json?$q=" + search;
```

check the documentation they have many functions that you might want to look.